# Using SVN commands alongside git-svn: Possible? Advisable?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, interop, git-svn

I was able to do the following without any problems:

1. Clone a remote SVN repo via `git svn clone`.
2. Make commits to the local git repo via `git add` and `git commit`.
3. Push git commits to the remote SVN repo via `git svn dcommit`.

But because I noticed `svn status` not reflecting the `dcommit`'ed changes in my local `.svn/` repo, AND because I wanted to *"have a nice, clean feeling about SVN-git interoperability"* as far as my local `.svn/` and `.git/` repos are concerned, I tried doing an **`svn update`** also (following the `git svn dcommit`). **This, however, resulted in SVN conflicts!**

In the articles on the web talking about `git-svn` usage, I'm seeing no mention of `svn update` following a `git svn dcommit`. It seems no one wants to use SVN once `git-svn` is working.

**Question: Does use of `git-svn` specifically forbid you from using SVN commands (like `svn update`)? If no, how do I easily bring by local `.svn/` repo up-to-date?**

Other than a mere *"nice, clean feeling of SVN-git interoperability"* that I mentioned above, I would also like to be able to switch to the SVN command-set if needed, say, when troubleshooting SVN revisions with a colleague at my disk who's not using `git-svn` (like everyone else in the team!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must not** use two different VCS in the same worktree, this **must** fail horribly.

You can have an SVN checkout and a Git clone in different directories and use the one here and the other there. But sing SVN and Git in the same worktree **will not ever work**.

Both tools assume *they* are managing the worktree and if there are files that are different, then they are different, no matter what. How should the SVN command know that the file you added locally is the same as in the SVN repository. For the SVN client it is exactly like if you did the commit from another worktree or even another computer if you did it with `git-svn`.

Comment: *"Both tools assume they are managing the worktree..."* - Aha!

Comment: But as a `git-svn` user, it's natural for me to expect this tool to be aware of the local svn repo also and be able to manage it. If it can read/write from/to the remote SVN repo, why can it not possibly do the same with local SVN repo?! Any thoughts on this? Eg, as part of the `git svn dcommit` operation, it could also do an `svn update`, no?

Comment: So, basically my point is, if two VCSes were not knowing about each other, I can understand why they should fail. But `git-svn` is SUPPOSED to be aware of Svn too, right?

Comment: No, wouldn't make any sense at all. Either you have an SVN clone or a Git clone, that's it. It would be much too cumbersome and fragile to even try to maintain the local SVN metadata. And all for no additional gain at all. If you want to use both, you have two separate worktrees and you are fine.